# Qt can i set resources programmatically?

Tags: c++, qt

in Qt c++ , is there any way to set resources programmatically?
i want to let the user to set the exe icon and his html file that will be loaded into the application(QtWebKit).
so it will embedded in to the application that is currently are compiled using the resource Collection Files (.qrc)

Comment: `and the misc files to be embedded in to the application that is currently are compiled ` Where exactly do you want to include what? What is `misc files to be embedded`?

Comment: updated the question , basically i want to make simple configuration utility that the user could set his icons and files ( like html file) 
that can be embedded into the application to brand it as his .

Comment: So what you want is to change the files in the .qrc files? If that is the case, there is the resource file editor that comes with qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't "let" the user set the "exe" icon -- not without extra tools or code. You're free of course to use Windows APIs to modify the executable, but this is not guaranteed to work. If the application is installed in a safe manner, it'll run without administrative privileges and won't be able to modify its icon. Basically: it's a stupid idea. Don't do it.

You can of course change the icon of the application at runtime by using the following code:

```
void setIcon(QWidget* widget, QPixmap* pixmap);
{
   WId wid = widget->winId();
   HINSTANCE inst = (HINSTANCE)qWinAppInst();
   QPixmap large = pixmap->scaled(48, 48, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
   SendMessage(wid, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)large->toWinHICON());
   QPixmap small = pixmap->scaled(24, 24, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
   SendMessage(wid, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)small->toWinHICON());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The files in the Qt resource system **cannot be changed** during runtime of your application, and thus not "programatically", if I understand you correctly.

You can, however, programatically (using a script in the build process) generate the .qrc file, if this is what you want. But I guess this is *not* what you want, since you are talking about *the user*, who most likely doesn't want to recompile your application to use it.

If you want to let the user choose between a couple of icons (as an example; but this may apply for other customisations) and let them choose a custom file. You could abstract from the Qt resources and the real file system by first scanning a subfolder of your application for an icon and then the resources (just prepend `:/` to the path after the local version doesn't exist). So the user may "overwrite" all resource files using local files for which you use this method.

I successfully applied this method for language files, as another example. There are files in `:/lang/` for some default languages, but the user may also place files in `<appdir>/lang/` and use them. Remember that you may need to search for suitable files in the directory during runtime, if the user may also choose between available files.

Comment: yep , well im looking for away to let the user to configure the app look and feel
for example how does windows let the user to set exe icon ?

Comment: @user63898 The icon of a windows executable is part of the executable file itself (maybe there are other ways, but I only know this). Using Qt, the executable icon will be part of your build step. You can however set the icon of a link on the Desktop or in the Start menu without altering the executable behind the link. For this, you need to know the location of the link itself, which you can't know when your app is running, but the user can change link icons using the properties dialog anyway, so I don't see the need for changing the icon programmatically within your running application...